# Console on chrome devtools displaying errors to bundle not component

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error that will make my chrome dev tools display the error pointing to the bundle.js, any time I search it via google or here I get things relating to webpack, but this error just randomly started happening I have not changed anything. All things are up to date, also the console tells me to download react dev tools even tho I have them installed already. any help would be appreciated thank you.

[local host in chrome, showing bundle.js instead of component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHDmW.png)

[vsCode showing package.json and app to show where log is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3gHe.png)

Comment: Tested by opening local host on firefox and it DOES show to correct file and location of the console log. so i belive its an issue with chrome but im not certain why i would be having the issue and none of my peers do.

Comment: i am facing this issue do you have any work around

Comment: I am facing this issue as well. Any luck here ?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using create-react-app that packages webpack internally, generates sourcemaps OOTB, you can't control it unless you [eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) your project or use a configuration override like craco but it's unlikely to be culprit here.

Seemingly a corrupt chrome build, you can try a few things:

- Ensure "Enable JavaScript Source Maps" is checked in devtools settings: [Enable Source Maps](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/source-maps/#enable_source_maps_in_settings)
  [image]
- Check the behaviour incognito
- Reinstall Chrome